# Rental car from Dublin to Scotland and return

Tags: automobiles, ferries, rental

Can you hire a Rental car in Dublin, travel to Scotland,  and return the car to Dublin (the trip would be about a week).

Comment: With some rental cars - yes. With every rental car in Ireland - no. Will it cost extra - maybe...

Comment: The suggested duplicate is more restrictive, but it should answer your question.